# sum values in one column for unique values in another column

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel 2010 worksheet tracking homeless client data for a cold weather shelter for families.  Each family is assigned a number.  If there are 5 members in the family, they will all have the same unique family number.  The Family # is in column D of the spreadsheet.  One of the family members is designated as Household Head with a Y in column H.  Only one family member will have a Y in this column. If any of the family members have an income of any kind, that annual income amount is entered in column W.  In column X on the row with a Y in column H, I need a formula that will sum the income for that unique family.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy without any screenshot or sample data.  But assuming I understand your question correctly, you can use either `SUMPRODUCT` or `SUMIFS` to achieve your goal.  And here is the screenshot.

[image]

- **`SUMPRODUCT`**: Say if you enter your formula in `cell X2`

  `=SUMPRODUCT(--(D:D=1),--(H:H="Y"),W:W)`
- **`SUMIFS`**: Say if you enter your formula in `cell X3`

  `=SUMIFS(W:W,D:D,1,H:H,"Y")`

But for family number is 1, the household head would be Y.  Maybe you can even leave the H:H condition out of both formulas.  But anyway, try and let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I couldn't seem to get a screen shot added.  The formulas don't do what I need.

Comment: There is an `edit` button under your post (above the tag) that you can add the screenshot there.